# Conditions for a sorted partition of the edges of $K_n$ to generate a total order of the vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring, set-partition

Given a complete undirected graph $K_n$, it's given a refinement algorithm that builds, at iteration $t$, a sorted partition $E^t$ of the edges and a sorted partition $V^t$ of the vertices by refining the partitions $E^{t-1}$ and $V^{t-1}$, calculated in the previous iteration, where the initial vertex partition is $V^0=\{V(G)\}$ (trivial partition) and the initial edge partition $E^0$ is input of the problem and can be any sorted partition.

The ingredients of the algorithm are:

- If $k_x$ is the key of an element $x$, to refine a sorted partition $P=\left[P_1, \ldots, P_l\right]$ based on such keys, for each $P_i$, split $P_i$ in new parts by grouping its elements by key, sort the new parts by the key they represent, and replace $P_i$ by the new parts in the same order. If $x\in P_i$, we say $x$ has **rank** $i$.
- Vectors used as keys are compared lexicographically.
- Given a vertex $v$, its key at iteration $t$ is a vector of size $|E^{t-1}|$ where its $i$-th element is the degree of $v$ in $K_n[E^{t-1}_i]$.
- Given edge $uv$, its key at turn $t$ is the 2-vector $[\min(r_u, r_v), \max(r_u, r_v)]$, where $r_u$ and $r_v$ are the ranks of $u$ and $v$ in $V^t$.

The algorithm is obvious now: turn $t$ is defined by refining $V^{t-1}$ using $E^{t-1}$ to calculate the vertex keys and so build $V^t$, and then refine $E^{t-1}$ using the refined $V^t$ to calculate the edge keys and so build $E^t$. If $V^{t-1}=V^t$ the algorithm stops and outputs $V^*\colon=V^t$.

I want to understand the properties of this algorithm better, so **my question is:**

- What are the necessary and sufficient conditions the initial edge partition $E^0$ must satisfy so that $|V^*|=n$ (so that $E^0$ finds a total order of the vertices using the algorithm above)?

It's obvious that if at any step $s$ of the algorithm all $K_n[E^s_i]$ are regular graphs of order $n$ then $|V^*|\lt n$.

The context is that I have millions of different such initial edge partitions and I want to "filter-out" as fast as possible all of those that will turn $V(G)$ into a total order, without having to know which total order that would be. This problem lead me to generalize it as the question I'm asking here, because I want to understand better the combinatorial properties of the problem.

I've tried to look in the existing literature but despite its similarity with other partition refinement and vertex-coloring algorithms, I haven't been able to find a description of my particular version.

Comment: There is almost certainly not a simple necessary and sufficient condition, but it also sounds like you don't need that for your application. Assuming "filter out" means you want to discard the partitions that turn $V(G)$ into a total order (but this is not clear from your question - maybe you mean the opposite?), you just want some easy-to-check sufficient condition that addresses most cases.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I want a test produces_total_order($E^0$)? If yes, I remove $E^0$; otherwise I don't. So yes, I can do a fast filtering first and use the full algorithm later, but the purpose of the question isn't really solving the problem but understanding its properties to buid intuition for other questions. Will a permutation of $E^0$ give a permutation of $V^*$? Can I merge some of its parts to get a shorter partition giving the same $V^*$? What is the minimal set $N^0$ so all $E^0$s giving a total order are derived from elements of $N^0$? Can I rebuilt $E^{s-1}, V^{s-1}$ from $E^s, V^s$?

Comment: That's way I generalized the question towards "necessary and sufficient conditions".

Comment: I worry that asking for that much means you won't get an answer to your question because you've made it that much harder...

Comment: @MishaLavrov these additional questions are in a comment. The original question ask only one thing. I have rewritten it a bit.